# UIButton prevent action for ControlState

Tags: objective-c, events

I got a UIButton which has two actions for two different control events: `UIControlEventTouchDown` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Is it possible to "block" the action bound to the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, if the action triggered by `UIControlEventTouchDown` detects that this is needed?

I can't change the code which belongs to the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`-action, because it's part of a private framework, so I have to find another way to help my self …

Comment: So you need to know if the `UIControlEventTouchDown` action actually triggered something, without being able to modify the code for that action at all?  Sounds kind of impossible to me

Comment: I have full control over the `UIControlEventTouchDown` action and I'd like to know if there is a way to prevent the UIButton from triggering other actions bound to it if `UIControlEventTouchDown` action detects that something is wrong with the submitted form.

Comment: You said you can't change the code, now you're saying you have full control?

Comment: Damn, sorry mixed something up. So if have full control over the `UIControlEventTouchDown` action but not the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` action which is inside a private framework …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action for `UIControlEventTouchDown` in the event that you want the `UIControlEvenTouchUpInside` not to trigger, you could set a different (probably empty) action for that event on the button, or just remove that action.  Hold onto a selector reference or just know the method name of the other action it should normally trigger, and reset it if you want it to trigger:

```
if ( buttonUsedDownAction )
{
    [button removeTarget:(self?) action:@selector(yourPrivateFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
else
{
    if ( [button actionsForTarget:(self?) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside].length == 0 )
    {
        [button addTarget:(self?) action:@selector(yourPrivateFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

I put `(self?)` for the target, because I'm not sure if self is the receiver of the Touch up inside action, but you should get the idea

Answer (score 1):

Make the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event dependent on a boolean variable (inside an if-statement). However you're notified that

> the action triggered by UIControlEventTouchDown detects that this is needed

use this notification to set the variable.

Comment: +1 But as mentioned in my question: *I can't change the code which belongs to the UIControlEventTouchDown-action, because it's part of a private framework, so I have to find another way to help my self …*

Comment: I did see that, but I assumed you'd have to be notified in some way - otherwise your goal seems logically impossible.